# "Error 'SetWindowTextA': is not a member of 'CStatic' and char *fgets(char*, int, FILE*): can not convert argument 1 from 'TCHAR' to 'char*'

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc

I migrated my C++ project from Visual Studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2017 Professional and when i build in Debug and Release modes i am getting the below errors:

1.

In the Debug build when I use SetWindowTextA like as shown below, I am getting the error "Error C2039 'SetWindowTextA': is not a member of 'CStatic'

```
m_status_text.SetWindowTextA(theStr);
```

m_status_text is declared as CStatic like as shown below:

```
CStatic m_status_text;
```

If I use SetWindowTextW, it is throwing an error in the Release Build.

```
m_status_text.SetWindowTextW(theStr);
```

When I changed it to "SetWindowText" like as shown below it is working for both Debug and Release Builds. Is it the correct way?

```
m_status_text.SetWindowText(theStr);
```

As far as my knowledge when we use "SetWindowText", in the Unicode format it treats it as "SetWindowTextW" and for multibyte character set format it treats as "SetWindowTextA".

But how SetWindowText works for Debug and Release builds?

2.

And also Can we use "_fgetts" instead of "fgets" (For release build) "fgetws" (For debug build) as in Debug build if i use "fgets", i am getting the below error:

char *fgets(char*, int, FILE*): can not convert argument 1 from 'TCHAR[260]' to 'char*'

```
fgets(currDir,MAX_PATH,f);    // For release build
fgetws(currDir, MAX_PATH, f); // For Debug build
```

3. Can I use "_tfopen" instead of "fopen" (For release build) and "_wfopen" (For debug build)

   f = _tfopen(fileName, _T("r"));

In place of

```
f = fopen(fileName,"r");  // For release build
f = _wfopen(fileName, L"r"); // For Debug build
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Do a UNICODE build not an ansi build. MBCS/SBCS apis are obsolete unless you are still targeting Windows 98.

Answer (score 2):

Windows API has 2 variants for each function that handles or allows strings as parameters:

- UNICODE, usually function name will end with W
- ANSI: function name will end with A

the Windows API then provides a common variant for all those functions, without the trailing A or W letter, that will map to one of the above (A or W) depending if UNICODE is defined or not.

Example:

> SetWindowText

is mapped to:
- [SetWindowTextA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowtexta) if UNICODE is NOT defined (=> ANSI)
- [SetWindowTextW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowtextw) if UNICODE is defined

The UNICODE variant handles strings as wchar_t*,
while the ANSI variant handled strings as char*.

TCHAR is a macro-defined character type that maps to char or wchar_t depending on UNICODE being defined or not:
- TCHAR = char if UNICODE is NOT defined
- TCHAR = wchar_t if UNICODE is defined

For "modern" Windows applications, VS2017 uses UNICODE mode by default (it's an option for the VC++ project file) and I suggest you stay with that,  unless you absolutely must support ancient versions of Windows (i.e. 98).
using UNICODE mode, you'll use the SetWindowTextW() function variants (or just SetWindowText()) and you will pass it a wchar_t* (or TCHAR*) string.

Use of TCHAR type may be wanted if you need to support or compile the project in BOTH ANSI AND UNICODE mode, but nowadays it's rarely needed.

Comment: This doesn't address the question. Neither `SetWindowTextA` nor `SetWindowTextW` are members of MFC's [CStatic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cstatic-class) implementation (or base classes).

Comment: @IInspectable there is a [`SetWindowText()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=vs-2017#setwindowtext) method in the base `CWnd` class. But the `#define` macros for the Win32 [`SetWindowText()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowtextw) function in `winuser.h` are altering the declaration of `CWnd::SetWindowText()` to be either `CWnd::SetWindowTextA()` or `CWnd::SetWindowTextW()` at compile-time, depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined. This is a result of Microsoft's C-oriented, C++-ignorant, `TCHAR` handling.

Comment: @IInspectable this is why it is dangerous to give C++ class methods the same names as Win32 API function names (at least for functions that have `TCHAR`-based parameters).

Comment: @RemyLebeau there is no `CWnd::SetWindowTextA` or `CWnd::SetWindowTextW`. Although `wnd->SetWindowTextW` does compile if Unicode is set. But I am not sure how ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53624512/

Comment: @BarmakShemirani **I** know there is no `CWnd::SetWindowText(A|W)()`, **you** know it, but the **compiler** doesn't! `winuser.h` has `#define SetWindowText SetWindowText(A|W)` statements that **blindly replace all occurances** of `SetWindowText` with `SetWindowText(A|W)`. The method is named `CWnd::SetWindowText()` in code, but the compiler sees `CWnd::SetWindowText(A|W)()` instead. That is the danger of **preprocessor macro substitution** in this situation. It happens during the preprocessing stage *before* the compilation stage begins.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani and then you end up with mismatches between the class declaration used in app code, vs the class implementation that gets linked to.

Answer (score 2):

In your question, you seem to mix two axes that are orthogonal to each other: ANSI vs. Unicode builds, and Debug vs. Release builds.

RE #1 the ANSI vs. Unicode function calls, when you invoke MFC class methods, you should simply invoke the *"undecorated"* method names, e.g.:

```
// Note the use of the "undecorated" SetWindowText method call:
m_status_text.SetWindowText(theStr);

// This gave you an error:
// m_status_text.SetWindowTextA(theStr);
```

This is *independent* from Debug vs. Release builds, which affect other aspects like run-time performance. In fact, in general in debug builds there's more code that gets compiled and checks invariants and other safety aspects, like making sure that indexes don't cross safe array boundaries, or proper iterator usage with STL containers, etc.
All these additional debug-build checks tend to produce less efficient code, but these same debug checks help you detect various bugs, that you can fix before shipping a more efficient Release build of your application.

But, again, this is independent from the ANSI vs. Unicode build mode aspect.

---

RE #2 The use of *different* file functions in Release vs. Debug builds: if you *really* need that (Are you sure? What are you actually trying to achieve?), you can use an `#ifdef` like this:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
   // Debug-build specific code
   // ...
#else 
   // Release-build specific code
   // ...
#endif
```

Of course you can use `fopen`, `_wfopen` and `_tfopen` in both Debug and Release builds: again, these Unicode/MBCS and Debug/Release builds are orthogonal.

**P.S.** 
In general, I would encourage you to move your code base to Unicode, and just build in Unicode mode (both Debug-Unicode and Release-Unicode).

Comment: To clarify, it is possible (though I can't fathom WHY it is possible) for Debug and Release builds to have different character set settings, so that, e.g. `SetWindowTextA` compiles in Debug but not in Release mode. Apparently this is the case for the OP. Always make sure that these settings are the same on both configurations!