# How does MFC interpret SetWindowTextW(LPCTSTR)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

In MFC there are no methods defined as `CWnd::SetWindowTextA`/`CWnd::SetWindowTextW`, yet the following code will compile and run correctly depending on Unicode settings:

```
//UNICODE is defined
BOOL CMyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    //this line won't compile as expected
    //SetWindowTextA(L"ANSI");

    //this line compiles, but CWnd::SetWindowTextW doesn't exits
    //SetWindowTextW ends up calling CWnd::SetWindowText
    SetWindowTextW(L"Unicode");
    return TRUE;
}

//UNICODE is not defined
BOOL CMyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog(); 

    //this line compiles, but CWnd::SetWindowTextA doesn't exits!
    //SetWindowTextA ends up calling CWnd::SetWindowText
    SetWindowTextA("ANSI");

    //this line won't compile as expected
    //SetWindowTextW(L"Unicode");
    return TRUE;
}
```

It makes sense that `SetWindowText` is mapped in to `SetWindowTextA`/`SetWindowTextW` depending on the macro. But I don't understand how `wnd->SetWindowTextA`/`wnd->SetWindowTextW` get mapped back in to `CWnd::SetWindowText`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a side effect of the macro declaration in `WinUser.h`.  It applies not only to the global function declaration for the Windows API, but also any other identifier named `SetWindowText` that appears in code: global, local, or class scope.

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define SetWindowText  SetWindowTextW
#else
#define SetWindowText  SetWindowTextA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

So any C++ class that declares a method called `SetWindowText` gets all that method implicitly converted by the preprocessor.

I don't have MFC installed, but I do know this method exists for the CWindow class on ATL and is defined as follows.

```
    class CWindow
    {
    public:
        ...

        BOOL SetWindowText(_In_z_ LPCTSTR lpszString) throw()
        {
            ATLASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd));
            return ::SetWindowText(m_hWnd, lpszString);
        }

        ...
    };
```

But at compile time, the above code (for a debug build) is going to get converted by the preprocessor into something like the following:

```
BOOL SetWindowTextW(  LPCTSTR lpszString) throw()
{
    (void)( (!!((::IsWindow(m_hWnd)))) || (1 != _CrtDbgReportW(2, L"c:\\program files...
    return ::SetWindowTextW(m_hWnd, lpszString);
}
```

Ironically, the LPCTSTR method parameter is typedef'd instead of being a macro replacement, but you get the idea.

If you have a large enough Windows application, chances are very high that one of your existing C++ classes that you defined yourself has a method or member variable that matches a Windows API.  And it's getting the same treatment.